# Regex pattern that matches SQL object (table/function/view)?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, regex, vb.net

Question:

Given a SQL string like

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS
SELECT value1, value2 
FROM TABLE_0
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_2) AS value1
,value2 
FROM TABLE_12 
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_3
```

(in lowercase)

And an array of string like

```
string[] tables = new string[]{"table_1", "table_2", "table_3"}
```

Now I did:

```
if (strViewDefinition.Contains(strObjectName)) // aaaaargh
```

for each strObjectName in tables, to check whether or not the view depends on this object.

But this fails on table_12 (and results in cyclic dependencies) for example, because tables contains "table_1". Aaargh.

I need a regex that can check if the view definition contains a function name, table-valued function or another view...

(
For checking with
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
)

My trial was:

```
string whateverneedsescaping= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(@"+-*\/%=,\n\r");
string fieldsep = @"[\s\n\r," + whateverneedsescaping+ "]*";
string strPattern = fieldsep + "VIEW/FUNCTION_NAME" + fieldsep;
```

But it fails, plus it doesn't account for object names embraced in brackets, like

```
 "[TABLE_NAME]"
```

Anybody can help ?

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Yes THIS is SQL-Server. But SQL-Server 2005. Plus it is intended for other Db systems as well, so don't recommend me SMO's (buggy on SQL 2005 as well btw) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
string strSchema = "dbo";
string strRegexObjectName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(strObjectName);
string strPattern = @"[\s\+\-\(,/%=\*\\](\[?" + strSchema + @"\]?\.)?\[?" + strRegexObjectName + @"\]?([\s\+\-\),/%=\*\\]|$)";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason it doesn't work is because you have the `-` character in your set. This character is not escaped by `Regex.Escape` and so your character set ends up containing the following:

```
[\s\n\r,\+-\*\\/%=,\\n\\r]
```

The `-` in this set tries to create a range between the literal characters `+` and `*` which doesn't make any sense and hence it throws an ArgumentException with the message `[x-y] range in reverse order`.

While i'm not 100% sure i understand your exact requirements, i think that the suggestion about using word boundaries from Qtax would work.

All i would add is that you could account for the table names surrounded with `[]` by changing it to:

```
\[?\btable_1\b]?
```

Answer (score 1):

Would the expression `\bname\b` suffice? `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

For example `\btable_1\b` would not match `table_12`.

If you have many names you could check for them all together with an expression like `\b(?:foo|bar|baz)\b`.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that (word boundary), but thanks for the suggestion of doing it all in one.